# avr-gcc optimization deleting register writes on ATTiny402

Tags: avr, attiny, c++, avr-gcc

I'm using avr-gcc (12.1.0, built with this script: https://github.com/ZakKemble/avr-gcc-build) to compile for the ATtiny402 and encountering problems with code optimization. Specifically, the compiler appears to be 'optimizing out' repeated writes to register variables, in some circumstances. So, if I compile this with `-Os` (required for timing functionality, apparently, as well as for avoiding huge binaries), it doesn't work (i.e. the pin output does not change as expected):

```
void led (uint8_t status)
{
    if (status)
        PORTA.OUTSET |= PIN6_bm;
    else
        PORTA.OUTCLR |= PIN6_bm;
}

int main ()
{
    PORTA.DIRSET |= PIN6_bm;

    led (0);
    _delay_ms (1000);
    led (1);
    _delay_ms (100);
    led (0);
    _delay_ms (100);
    led (1);
    _delay_ms (100);
    led (0);
    _delay_ms (100);
    led (1);
    _delay_ms (100);
    led (0);

    return 0;
}
```

The pin output goes high, but does not go low afterwards. The above *does* work if I turn off gcc optimization.

The following works just fine, both with and without optimization:

```
int main ()
{
    PORTA.DIRSET |= PIN6_bm;

    PORTA.OUTCLR |= PIN6_bm;
    _delay_ms (1000);
    PORTA.OUTSET |= PIN6_bm;
    _delay_ms (100);
    PORTA.OUTCLR |= PIN6_bm;
    _delay_ms (100);
    PORTA.OUTSET |= PIN6_bm;
    _delay_ms (100);
    PORTA.OUTCLR |= PIN6_bm;
    _delay_ms (100);
    PORTA.OUTSET |= PIN6_bm;
    _delay_ms (100);
    PORTA.OUTCLR |= PIN6_bm;

    return 0;
}
```

I've taken a (very quick) look at the generated assembly language, and it does look like this is an optimization feature (it seems to have created two different versions of the led function).

I can avoid the problem by applying `#pragma` directives to the function, but it feels 'messy' and I would very much like to understand what's happening here.

I'm not sure this is the best place to post this, as it's a compiler issue rather than hardware, but I'm hoping that somebody here might have seen this before.

EDIT to add excerpt of generated assembly language (optimized):

```
_Z3ledh.part.0:
/* prologue: function */
/* outgoing args size = 0 */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    ldi r30,0
    ldi r31,lo8(4)
    ldd r24,Z+5
    ori r24,lo8(64)
    std Z+5,r24
/* epilogue start */
    ret
    .size   _Z3ledh.part.0, .-_Z3ledh.part.0

...

_Z3ledh:
/* prologue: function */
/* outgoing args size = 0 */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    tst r24
    breq .L6
    rcall _Z3ledh.part.0
    ret
.L6:
    lds r24,1030
    ori r24,lo8(64)
    sts 1030,r24
/* epilogue start */
    ret

... 

main:
/* prologue: function */
/* outgoing args size = 0 */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    lds r24,1025
    ori r24,lo8(64)
    sts 1025,r24
    ldi r24,0
    rcall _Z3ledh
    ldi r18,lo8(3199999)
    ldi r24,hi8(3199999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(3199999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    rcall _Z3ledh.part.0
    ldi r18,lo8(319999)
    ldi r24,hi8(319999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(319999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
```

EDIT: the following is the entire assembly generated for the original, non-working example:

```
    .file   "flashing-led.cpp"
__SP_H__ = 0x3e
__SP_L__ = 0x3d
__SREG__ = 0x3f
__CCP__ = 0x34
__tmp_reg__ = 0
__zero_reg__ = 1
    .text
    .type   _Z3ledh.part.0, @function
_Z3ledh.part.0:
/* prologue: function */
/* outgoing args size = 0 */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    ldi r30,0
    ldi r31,lo8(4)
    ldd r24,Z+5
    ori r24,lo8(64)
    std Z+5,r24
/* epilogue start */
    ret
    .size   _Z3ledh.part.0, .-_Z3ledh.part.0
.global _Znwj
    .type   _Znwj, @function
_Znwj:
/* prologue: function */
/* outgoing args size = 0 */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    rcall malloc
/* epilogue start */
    ret
    .size   _Znwj, .-_Znwj
.global _ZdlPv
    .type   _ZdlPv, @function
_ZdlPv:
/* prologue: function */
/* outgoing args size = 0 */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    rcall free
/* epilogue start */
    ret
    .size   _ZdlPv, .-_ZdlPv
.global _ZdlPvj
    .type   _ZdlPvj, @function
_ZdlPvj:
/* prologue: function */
/* outgoing args size = 0 */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    rcall free
/* epilogue start */
    ret
    .size   _ZdlPvj, .-_ZdlPvj
.global _Z3ledh
    .type   _Z3ledh, @function
_Z3ledh:
/* prologue: function */
/* outgoing args size = 0 */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    tst r24
    breq .L6
    rcall _Z3ledh.part.0
    ret
.L6:
    lds r24,1030
    ori r24,lo8(64)
    sts 1030,r24
/* epilogue start */
    ret
    .size   _Z3ledh, .-_Z3ledh
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.global main
    .type   main, @function
main:
/* prologue: function */
/* outgoing args size = 0 */
/* frame size = 0 */
/* stack size = 0 */
.L__stack_usage = 0
    ldi r30,0
    ldi r31,lo8(4)
    ldd r24,Z+1
    ori r24,lo8(64)
    std Z+1,r24
    ldi r24,0
    rcall _Z3ledh
    ldi r18,lo8(3199999)
    ldi r24,hi8(3199999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(3199999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    rcall _Z3ledh.part.0
    ldi r18,lo8(319999)
    ldi r24,hi8(319999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(319999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    ldi r24,0
    rcall _Z3ledh
    ldi r18,lo8(319999)
    ldi r24,hi8(319999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(319999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    rcall _Z3ledh.part.0
    ldi r18,lo8(319999)
    ldi r24,hi8(319999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(319999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    ldi r24,0
    rcall _Z3ledh
    ldi r18,lo8(319999)
    ldi r24,hi8(319999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(319999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    rcall _Z3ledh.part.0
    ldi r18,lo8(319999)
    ldi r24,hi8(319999)
    ldi r25,hlo8(319999)
1:  subi r18,1
    sbci r24,0
    sbci r25,0
    brne 1b
    rjmp .
    nop
    ldi r24,0
    rcall _Z3ledh
    ldi r24,0
    ldi r25,0
/* epilogue start */
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 12.1.0"
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144842/discussion-on-question-by-andy28-avr-gcc-optimization-deleting-register-writes-o); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While having *no* idea why the code presented shouldn't work,
`led(uint8_t status)` should look

```
void led (uint8_t status)
{
    if (status)
        PORTA.OUTSET = PIN6_bm;
    else
        PORTA.OUTCLR = PIN6_bm;
}
```

to take advantage of those separate SET&CLR addresses.

Comment: Thank you very much; that fixed the problem.